# What does "no good" mean?

Tags: meaning

> 1. Here we are on the hills, and it's no better.
> 2. But ... but I will worry if I think you are hanging on waiting, because it's no good.
> 3. It's very easy to tell an actor that it's no good.

What do they actually mean?

Comment: This question would be much better if 1) you gave the source of each quote.  and 2) You explained what you think each one means.  What are you confused about.  What do you think it might mean?

Answer (score 1):

Something is "no good" means it is too bad, or it is not good enough for the what is needed.

> This hammer is no good.  It is too small to break up these stones.

In your examples, 1. means simply "it has not become more good".  3. means "it is easy to tell them that something is not good enough". 2. is very oddly phrased and nearly impossible to understand without more context.  It says "it's is not good enough", but there is no way to know what "it" means.

Comment: Saying 'it's no good' about some action can mean that it is hopeless or very unlikely to succeed, e.g. it's no good asking Mary for a date because she only goes out with champion athletes, or 'it's no good planting seeds in bad soil because nothing will grow' and I wonder if that is the sense intended here.